# how to get react app to display api data as html instead of string when passed as prop

Tags: reactjs, json, api, material-ui, react-props

i am trying to display a block of text i got from a recipe api, the text includes html elements like bold tags and links, but is wrapped in a string so its displaying the literal text [current text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQRiB.jpg)

i need it to display the text not as a string but as jsx [desired text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leF0H.jpg)

i am passing the api data through props  `const RecipeDetail = ({ recipeDetail }) => { const { image, analyzedInstructions, extendedIngredients, instructions, summary, title } = recipeDetail;`
i am trying to use summary, also im using material ui `<Stack gap={4} sx={{ backgroundColor:'grey', borderRadius: '12px'}}> <Typography sx={{ borderBottom: 'solid red', marginRight: 'auto'}} variant='h4'> Summary </Typography> <Typography paragraph="true" align='justify' gutterBottom='true' variant='body1' sx={{ lineHeight: '2rem' }}> {summary} </Typography> </Stack>`
as you can see i am passing the summary in as prop because it changes based on what recipe is selected

,
so how do i stop the summary from being passed in as a string

i got the desired version by passing in the jsx in as the summary [desired text code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0IQ7.png) but the summary wont change based on which recipe is selected

Comment: maybe can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property on Typography like this:

```
<Typography dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: summary }}></Typography>
```

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) is the React docs about it