# return the element's data attributes in an object

Tags: javascript

this is my code:

```js
const dataset = (element) => {
  // TODO: return the element's data attributes in an object

};
```

I need to do this:

Implement the `dataset` function which takes one `element` parameter (of type `String`) and returns an `Object` with the right keys and values:

```js
const burger = `<div class="card" data-id="42" data-price="15" data-category="popular">
  <div class="card-category">Popular</div>
  <div class="card-description">
    <h2>The best burger in town (15€)</h2>
  </div>
</div>`;

dataset(burger);
// => { id: 42, price: 15, category: 'popular' }
```

- It should only return the dataset of the **wrapping** element regardless of its children
- It should cast the values to the right type (in the example, `42` and `15` should be `number`s)

im really new and trying to learn as much as possible i don't have any clue on hoe to do this

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js for how to parse the HTML to a DOM element. Then use the `dataset` property to get all the data attributes.

Comment: There's nothing that will automatically convert the numeric properties to numbers. You'll need to check for that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object from that html code then grab the dataset of the first child. While copying that, convert to int.

```js
const burger = `<div class="card" data-id="42" data-price="15" data-category="popular">
  <div class="card-category">Popular</div>
  <div class="card-description">
    <h2>The best burger in town (15€)</h2>
  </div>
</div>`;

const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.innerHTML = burger;
const dataset = wrapper.firstElementChild.dataset;
const data = {};
for (const key in dataset) {
  data[key] = isNaN(dataset[key]) ? dataset[key] : Number(dataset[key]);
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I'd use `const data = { ...wrapper.firstElementChild.dataset }` and then subsequently loop over the keys in `data` and use `data[key]` directly.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply** write this way with reusable approach!

```js
const dataset = ( element ) => {
  let tmpDiv = document.createElement('div');
      tmpDiv.innerHTML = element;
  let res = {
        id: tmpDiv.querySelector('.card').getAttribute('data-id'),
        price: tmpDiv.querySelector('.card').getAttribute('data-price') ,
        category: tmpDiv.querySelector('.card').getAttribute('data-category') 
      }
  return res
};



const burger = `<div class="card" data-id="42" data-price="15" data-category="popular">
  <div class="card-category">Popular</div>
  <div class="card-description">
    <h2>The best burger in town (15€)</h2>
  </div>
</div>`;


console.log( dataset(burger) )
```

Comment: How is this reusable...? It relies on the input to always have an element with a `card` class and only gives you the `id`, `price`, and `category`, which may or may not exist, and may or may not include all the dataset elements.