# How to replace a string with another string in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, replace

I am fetching data *(html content)* from an API and setting it as an *dangerioslyinnerhtml* in ***ReactJS***. I want to make an image popup using *fancyapps/UI* and in order to do that, I have to replace this,

```
<div className="img-parent">
    <img className='fancybox' src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

with this

```
<Fancybox options={{ infinite: false }}>
    <button
      data-fancybox="gallery"
      data-src={require("source-of-image")}
      className="button button--secondary">
      <img className='fancybox' src={require("source-of-image")} alt="" />
    </button>
</Fancybox>
```

Any ideas with `.replaceAll` function in JS?

I tried to explain my problem in details and I want some experienced people to help.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you encounter a problem? Why should a string be replaced(a block of html in your case) to make an image pop up?

Comment: I tried using .replaceAll  and its easy to replace the start of the image(replacing <img with <Fancybox options={{ infinite: false }}>
  
    <button
      data-fancybox="gallery"
      data-src={require("source-of-image")}
      className="button button--secondary"
    >
      <img) but I cant find the end of the div to  place end of fancybox . I want to replace the string because I have to place an image as a child of <Fancybox> component in order it to work as a popup-slider

Comment: Can you not add a ternary operator and display the first code or the second according to a state ?

Comment: Why are you fetching HTML in the first place? Can't you just get the image source?

Comment: yes, I can control it using state. am fetching HTML because it comes from CMS which creates content pages using HTML, it is inside of text so I cant get img source particularly

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to parse the response you are getting as html as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js):

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, 'text/html');
```

and then you get the data you need to display your FancyBox components like this:

```
const images = [];
htmlDoc.querySelectorAll(".img-parent img").forEach(img=>{
   images.push({src:img.src, alt:img.alt})
});
```

Comment: queryselector in react? no man, that is anti-pattern

Comment: No, in this case it's used after 
 fetching and parsing the html string. Not on the page DOM.