# Insert tag at specific position using javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have string like :

```
var txtstr='<p>Text 1</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Text &nbsp;2</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Text 3&nbsp;</p>';
```

i have one `<img src=..../>` i want to insert image tag at specific p tag position.

for eg. 5th `<p> tag` and after 7th characters here `&nbsp` will be counted as one character only there can be multiple `&nbsp`

i was trying like this

```
const paragraphs = str.split("</p>")
const firstParagraph = paragraphs[5]+'</p>';
```

but this was not working

Any solution, Thanks

Comment: *"I was trying like this..."*: I don't see any attempt to insert an image.

Comment: What if that 5th `<p>` has other HTML elements as children? What do you then consider as "after 7th characters"?

Comment: @trincot i'm facing issue in extracting correct `<p>` tag content , if there is some other tag this code returning those tag instead of specific position `<p>` tag, can you pls suggest some solution

Comment: OK, but in your code, where is the image?

Comment: @trincot there are two values which i have first is row number which denotes specific `<p>` tag and second is index like `5th` now i have to insert `<img>` tag inside that specific `<p>` tag specified index for eg  `<p>Text 3&nbsp;</p>`  5th `<p>` tag is this and after 8th index inside that tag here `&nbsp` will be counted as one characters, p tag can contain other html childrens also then they will be shifted

Comment: But what happens when that `<p>` has child elements, like `<p><i><b><span>hi</span></b><ul><li>one</li></ul></i></p>` I mean how do you *count* the 7th position? Do the elements count as 1? Nested elements also as 1? I don't understand.

Comment: And again, where in your code attempt is the image? I don't see it.

Comment: <p>Text 1</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Text &nbsp;2</p><p>&nbsp;</p><img src="path/to/your/image.jpg" /></p><p>Text 3&nbsp;</p>

is this the output you want

Comment: @Chethiya Hitihamu `<p>Text 1</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Text &nbsp;2</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Text 3&nbsp; <img src='....'> </p>` like this

Comment: @trincot i'm working on ckeditor from there i'm getting the current location of pointer now i have to modify the string based on the location and insert image tag on button click

Comment: If you are working within a browser, maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10585079/703233

Comment: It is the wrong approach to get the current location of the pointer. You should use DOM methods to insert content *at the pointer*. No string manipulation. If you cannot make it work that way, target your question on what you originally want to accomplish (insert image *at the caret position*, in a ckeditor).

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps

```js
// Your HTML string
var txtstr = "<p>Text 1</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Text &nbsp;2</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Text 3&nbsp;</p>";

// Define the position to insert the <img> tag (e.g., 5th paragraph)
const insertPosition = 4;

// Define the image source
const imgSrc = "path/to/your/image.jpg";

// Create the <img> tag
const imgTag = `<img src="${imgSrc}" />`;

// Split the string into paragraphs
const paragraphs = txtstr.split("</p>");

// Insert the <img> tag at the specified position
if (insertPosition >= 0 && insertPosition < paragraphs.length) {
  paragraphs[insertPosition] += ` ${imgTag}`;
}

// Join the paragraphs back together to form the modified HTML string
const modifiedTxtstr = paragraphs.join("</p>");

console.log(modifiedTxtstr);
```

Output is like this

```html
<p>Text 1</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Text &nbsp;2</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Text 3&nbsp; <img src="path/to/your/image.jpg" /></p>
```