# Trying to use the DOMParser with node js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I am running into issues when trying to use the DOMParser in my js code.  In my code, I retrieve an xml file via xmlhttp.responseText soap response.  I want to be able to access its elements in JSON format, so my code looks like:

```
var xml = new DOMParser();
xml = xml.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText, 'text/xml');
var result = xmlToJson(xml);
```

I get this error message:
    ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined

Edit:
This link hasn't worked for me because my javascript isn't in the HTML page, as it is a node.js file.  [JavaScript DOMParser access innerHTML and other properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250545/javascript-domparser-access-innerhtml-and-other-properties)

Answer (score 234, accepted):

A lot of browser functionalities, like DOM manipulations or XHR, are not available natively NodeJS because that is not a typical server task to access the DOM - you'll have to use an external library to do that.

DOM capacities depends a lot on the library, here's a quick comparisons of the main tools you can use:

- **[`jsdom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)**: implements DOM level 4 which is [the latest DOM standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model#Standards), so everything that you can do on a modern browser, you can do it in `jsdom`. It is the de-facto industry standard for doing browser stuff on Node, used by Mocha, Vue Test Utils, Webpack Prerender SPA Plugin, and many other:

  ```js
  const jsdom = require("jsdom");
  const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
  dom.window.document.querySelector("p").textContent; // 'Hello world'
  ```
- **[`deno_dom`](https://deno.land/x/deno_dom)**: if using Deno instead of Node is an option, this library provides DOM parsing capabilities:

  ```
  import { DOMParser } from "https://deno.land/x/deno_dom/deno-dom-wasm.ts";
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const document = parser.parseFromString('<p>Hello world</p>', 'text/html');
  document.querySelector('p').textContent; // 'Hello world';
  ```
- **[`htmlparser2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2)**: same as jsdom, but with enhanced performances and flexibility at the price of a more complex API:

  ```js
  const htmlparser = require("htmlparser2");
  const parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
    onopentag: (name, attrib) => {
      if (name=='p') console.log('a paragraph element is opening');
    }
  }, {decodeEntities: true});
  parser.write(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
  parser.end();
  // console output: 'a paragraph element is opening'
  ```
- **[`cheerio`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)**: implementation of jQuery based on HTML DOM parsing by `htmlparser2`:

  ```js
  const cheerio = require('cheerio');
  const $ = cheerio.load(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
  $('p').text('Bye moon');
  $.html(); // '<!DOCTYPE html><p>Bye moon</p>'
  ```
- **[`xmldom`](https://github.com/xmldom/xmldom)**: fully implements the DOM level 2 and partially implements the DOM level 3. Works with HTML, and with XML also
- **[`dom-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-parser)**: regex-based DOM parser that implements a few DOM methods like `getElementById`. Since parsing HTML with regular expressions is [a very bad idea](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) I wouldn't recommend this one for production.

Answer (score 29):

I used [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) because it's got a ton of usage and is written by a prominent web hero - no promises that it's behavior perfectly matches your browser (or even that every browser's behavior is the same) but it worked for me:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom")
const { JSDOM } = jsdom
global.DOMParser = new JSDOM().window.DOMParser
```

Comment: Great approach! Especially because in my case a 3rd-party library was using DOMParser.

Answer (score 23):

You can use a Node implementation of DOMParser, such as [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom). This will allow you to access DOMParser outside of the browser. For example:

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var document = parser.parseFromString('Your XML String', 'text/xml');
```

Comment: it does not work - just spits a lot of error "entity not found" when trying to parse an html page

Comment: xmldom is an old library. No querySelector support

Comment: `xmldom` is a poor substitute for DOMParser.  It does not correctly parse peer elements.

Comment: It satisfies my needs as I am actually implementing this logic! Thanks,
https://gist.github.com/chinchang/8106a82c56ad007e27b1

Comment: This is the replacement for the older xmldom package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@xmldom/xmldom

Answer (score 17):

There is no `DOMParser` in node.js, that's a browser thing. You can try any of these modules though:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-parsers-xml

Comment: I know this thread is old, but here it goes. What about jquery for node? An ajax call with dataType xml should receive an xml dom response.

Comment: The link provided appears to have expired.

Answer (score 5):

I really like [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2). It's a fantastic, fast and lightweight library. I've created a small demo on how to use it on RunKit: https://runkit.com/jfahrenkrug/htmlparser2-demo/1.0.0

Comment: it's good to know that additional packages that make it actually useful (css-select, domutils) are not free

Answer (score 3):

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    '<xml xmlns="a" xmlns:c="./lite">\n'+
        '\t<child>test</child>\n'+
        '\t<child></child>\n'+
        '\t<child/>\n'+
    '</xml>'
    ,'text/xml');
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed `DOMParser` in node. This is what I used

```js
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

class DOMParser {
  parseFromString(s, contentType = 'text/html') {
    return new JSDOM(s, {contentType}).window.document;
  }
}
```

now the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript) works for me.

```js
function htmlDecode(input) {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
  return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}

console.log(  htmlDecode("&lt;img src='myimage.jpg'&gt;")  )    
// "<img src='myimage.jpg'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use yet another DOM parser from html string to DOM and back > [Himalaya](https://github.com/andrejewski/himalaya), or at [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/himalaya):

```
import { parse, stringify } from 'himalaya';

const dom = parse(htmlString)

// Do something here

const htmlStringNext = stringify(dom)
```

Answer (score 0):

[RSS parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser) is easy for parsing Atom feeds. I you are using NextJs for example you can simply create an API like so:

```
import Parser from 'rss-parser'

export default async function API(req, res) {
    let parser = new Parser();
    try {
        const feed = await parser.parseURL(`https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/lg_image_of_the_day.rss`);
        if (feed) return res.json({ "message": `Here is your data feed title`, status: 200, data: feed.title })
    } catch (error) {
        return res.json({ "message": "You made an invalid request", status: 401 })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can as well use html-to-text in case you need html to text conversion as can be seen in few answers to this question.

```
const { convert } = require('html-to-text');
// There is also an alias to `convert` called `htmlToText`.

const options = {
  wordwrap: 130,
  // ...
};
const html = '<div>Hello World</div>';
const text = convert(html, options);
console.log(text); // Hello World
```