# Using DOMParser in javascript testing with mocha and JSDOM

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, sinon, jsdom

I'm having a problem testing some javascript that uses window.DOMParser

```
const stripLink = (url) => {
  const parser = new DOMParser()
  const link = parser.parseFromString(unescape(url), 
'text/html').querySelector('a')
  return link ? link.getAttribute('href') : url
}
```

When tested in mocha it gives a warning.

```
node:22883) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined
```

I'm guessing this is because there is no DOMParser in node. How do I get around this? I've tried various things like

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser
sinon.stub(window, 'DOMParser', DOMParser)
```

Thinking that if I replace window.DOMParser with xmldom parser for the tests it should work, but it doesn't.

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55668667/6666348

Answer (score 10):

**Update: 2020/12/02**

For modern versions of `js` there is no longer a need to install the dependency. Using `global.DOMParser = window.DOMParser` should be sufficient. Thanks [@tony-gentilcore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4615344/tony-gentilcore)

**Original Answer**

There is another similar workaround. You need to install the following packages:

```
npm install jsdom jsdom-global --save-dev
```

Then make sure to run the following code in a `setup.js` file or before the first test runs:

**setup.js**

```
require('jsdom-global')()
global.DOMParser = window.DOMParser
```

This will allow you to call `DOMParser` from within your `src`s files without extracting it from a global object.

**File Structure**

```
.
├── src
└── tests
    ├── setup.js
    └── some-test.spec.js
```

Comment: Just  `global.DOMParser = window.DOMParser` in setup.js without the dependency is enough these days.

Comment: @TonyGentilcore just updated based on your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Replacing

```
const parser = new DOMParser()
```

With

```
const parser = new window.DOMParser()
```

Did the trick. Seems JSDOM already supports DOMParser however you need to explicitly call window.DOMParser() in your code for it to work.