# Unable to pass response value from nodejs server to ajax function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I have sent data from `process()` function to `router.get` method.But I can't pass my `xmlString` variable of `router.get` method to `handleServerResponse()` method in test.js.It's showing internal server error.Please fix my problem.Thanks in advance.

my `test.js` file

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }else{
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert("Cant create that object");
    }else{
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}

function process(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        var food = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        console.log(food);

        xmlHttp.open("GET", "/start/" + food, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    } else {
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}



function handleServerResponse(){
    let xmlResponse;
    let xmlDocumentElement;
    let message;
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {

            console.log("check done");
             xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
             xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
             message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild;
             console.log(message);
            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = '<span style="color:blue"></span>';
            setTimeout('process()', 1000000);
        } else {
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
    }
}
```

my `index.js` file

```
router.get('/start/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id);

    var xmlString = "<div id='foo'><a href='#'>Hello BigGo</a><span></span></div>"
        , parser = new DOMParser()
        , doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
    var data='dip';
 });
```

my `add.hbs` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body >


<h3>The Chuff Bucket</h3>
Enter the foood you would like to order:
<input type="text" id="userInput" oninput="process()" />
<div id="underInput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What the error? Attach it

Comment: process() function is used to pass the value of input field in my router.get method.If i remove the brackets it doesn't work.The error is internal server error.

Comment: `setTimeout('process()', 1000000);` - this tries execute string, you probably need to change it to `setTimeout(process, 1000000);`

Comment: Man, there is no `DOMParser` in nodejs  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js

Comment: How can i pass a string from router.get method to  handleServerResponse() function???

Comment: `res.send(xmlString)`

Comment: I have tried it but can't catch it in the  handleServerResponse() function.How will i catch the string???

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro....It has worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add res.send(data) at the end of router.get() function