# how to add class to an element in a html string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a html string from backend API and I want to add class to all the image element in the html string, I was able to do it with jQuery but as jQuery doesn't work in server side rendering so I am looking for solutions in javascript.

here is the html string

```
let html="<p>here is a blog test<img src="https://bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/83a5e290-8a8d-11ea-8466.jpg"></p>"
```

I want to add class to the image element

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use **``** backticks to form your content, for example:

```
let html = `<p>here is a blog test<img src="https://bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/83a5e290-8a8d-11ea-8466.jpg" class=${className}></p>`
```

Comment: i am getting the html string from backend api and need to add the class dynamically  with extracting the image tags first

Comment: Could you perhaps explain more about what you mean? I don't quite understand what you mean by "extracting the email tags first"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to achieve this, there is also a way to do it with str.replace but its not a clean way in opinion, here is a working example:

```js
let html='<p>here is a blog test<img src="https://bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/83a5e290-8a8d-11ea-8466.jpg"></p>'


parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

let images = doc.firstChild.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(let i =0; i<images.length; i++) {
  images[i].classList.add('img-element');
  console.log(images[i]);
}
```

Comment: tried this but its throwing an error of DOMParser is not defined in node js server

Comment: @punitdas, didn't notice the SSR tag, I should have noticed it, DOMParser doesn't come with node, so you should use npm module for that also check if window.DOMParser is available or not, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js/55668667