# How to select from an html substring with node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have the following table:

```
function returnTable() {

    return `
    
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">\

    <tbody><tr>\
        <th>Type</th>\
                            <th>Description</th>\

                    <td class="table-number">$0</td>\


        <td class="table-number">$0</td>\

    </tr>\

</tbody></table>
`    
}
```

I want to be able to parse it with node using selectors. I see that document.queryselector appears to require a full html document.

I also tried:

```
function getTable1(page) {

    const newTable = document.createElement(page);
    console.log(newTable);
}

getTable1(returnTable())
```

But this gives:

```
const newTable = document.createElement(page);
                 ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

How to I parse an html substring in node? in other words use queryselector on a html fragment or substring?

Comment: `document` exists only in a browser. Do you write backend or what?

Comment: Yes I'm using node with pupeteer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use the DOMParser with node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js)