# Extract data from HTML string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodeJS script that reads HTML from a file as string.
I would like to extract some data from it.
My string (it is a string not HTML) is as following:

```
<tr><td style="text-align: center;">Initial Filing</td></tr>
                                        
<tr><td>Debtor</td></tr>

    <tr><td class="dName">PO</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="dAddress">CLACKAMAS OR 97015</td></tr>

<tr><td>Secured Party</td></tr>

    <tr><td class="spName">AS</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="spAddress">SPRINGFIELD IL 62708</td></tr>
    
<tr><td>Debtor</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="dName">ONE</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="dAddress">CLACKAMAS OR 97015</td></tr>

<tr><td>Secured Party</td></tr>

    <tr><td class="spName">ANY</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="spAddress">SPRINGFIELD IL 62708</td></tr>
```

The JavaScrit code I'm using is:

```
fs.readFile('file.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error reading file.txt", err);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        var cleanedHtml = /<tr><td>Debtor<\/td><\/tr>(.*?)<tr><td>Secured Party<\/td><\/tr>/g.exec(html);
        console.log(cleanedHtml[1]);
    });
```

It returns to me this:

```
 return cleanedHtml[1];
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

Is there any issue with my regex?
Also, how can I have an end result like this:

```
PO
CLACKAMAS OR 97015

AS
SPRINGFIELD IL 62708
    
ONE
CLACKAMAS OR 97015

ANY
SPRINGFIELD IL 62708
```

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need [an HTML parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser) rather than using regex.

Comment: I'd suggest two things to check:
1) in your regex instead of (.*?) try (.*)?
2) in the exec method, pass in data and not html (where is html defined?!).

Comment: html is also just an error when I was to simplify  the code I use to post it here, but I'm  passing the correct variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make sure that the `tr` elements are inside `<table></table>` then you can parse the string using [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/DOMParser) after reading the file:

**Demo:**

```js
var strHtml = `
  <table>
    <tr><td style="text-align: center;">Initial Filing</td></tr>

    <tr><td>Debtor</td></tr>

    <tr><td class="dName">PO</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="dAddress">CLACKAMAS OR 97015</td></tr>

    <tr><td>Secured Party</td></tr>

    <tr><td class="spName">AS</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="spAddress">SPRINGFIELD IL 62708</td></tr>

    <tr><td>Debtor</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="dName">ONE</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="dAddress">CLACKAMAS OR 97015</td></tr>

    <tr><td>Secured Party</td></tr>

    <tr><td class="spName">ANY</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="spAddress">SPRINGFIELD IL 62708</td></tr>
  </table>
  `

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(strHtml, 'text/html');
var els = doc.querySelectorAll('.dName,.spName,.dAddress,.spAddress');
els.forEach((el) => {
  console.log(el.textContent);
});
```

Comment: This is a script that runs by nodeJS. It says var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString("<table>" + strHtml + "</table>", 'text/html');
              ^

ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined

Comment: @DevDev, please follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js/55668667

Answer (score 0):

Should there not be brackets after console.log? Is the cleanedHtml a list with more than one element?  Otherwise there is no cleanedHtml[1]

Comment: Sorry that is just a typo, the real code is return cleanedHtml[1]; I updated the code above.