# Extract all HTML elements from Telegram Web page with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, telegram-bot

I want to extract all HTML elements from Telegram web website. I tried all methods e.g. get, post, get() jquery, methods from Python, JavaScript, ...

But when they return the result, it is incomplete and some part of it is missing. How can I do this correctly?

This a snippet that returns an incomplete alements:

```
fetch("https://web.telegram.org/k/")
  .then(x => x.text())
  .then(y => console.log(y));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned for Telegram Web scraping, we cannot use the traditional javascript codes or simple Python library. In this case, we MUST use Selenium and WebDriver and I'm working on it.
Any better suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this way,

```
// first install jsdom
// type npm i jsdom in the console.

const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

fetch("https://web.telegram.org/k/")
    .then(x => x.text())
    .then(y => {
        const { document } = (new JSDOM(y)).window;
        console.log(document)
});
```

checkout jsdom documantation:
https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

Comment: Thanks sir, but this code in VCS doesn't work. It jumps from line 2 to end. I don't see anything in terminal.

Comment: actually, you can't send get request to access content operating within the current origin.

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe

Comment: const parser = new DOMParser();
                       ^

ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined
    at C:\Users\Ali.Molaei\Desktop\javascript\firstscraper\scraperapi.js:26:24
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: are you using node js? node does not have DOMParser. you need to use a different dom parser library for this. is this slove your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js

Comment: When I installed the Allow-CORS extension for chrome, my code worked in chrome console and VCS, but again incomplete. Your code also works in console and not in VCS. But main problem still persists.

Comment: I've updated the answer. check if it helps your problem.

Comment: (node:3784) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Document { location: [Getter/Setter] }

Comment: This error is return by vsc.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to add header: "Application-Type" :"text/html"