# how to wrap javascript string with tag in another tag by regex?

Tags: javascript, html, string, dom

I have string with link

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Twitter/</a>
```

and I need to wrap a text inside link in a `<span>` element

like **:**

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span style="color: white">Twitter</span>/</a>
```

so what regex i need ?
ps. i need to send this string as part of html mail letter from mongodb via nodejs, not for manipulate DOM

Comment: Why don't you make use of the DOM for this or a parser instead of a regex?

Comment: it's not about layout or dom, it's about sending this string from mongodb via nodejs in html letter

Comment: If it is via nodejs, I think you can use a [DOMParser with node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js)

Comment: You can use DOM methods, then get the `outerHTML` to convert it to a string for sending email.

Answer (score 1):

It's safest to use a DOMParser with node.js as "The fourth bird" mentioned: [Trying to use the DOMParser with node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js)

You can use a regex, which might not cover all corner cases. Here are two options:

```js
const input = '<a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Twitter/</a>';

let regex1 = /(<a [^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/a>)/gi;
let result1 = input.replace(regex1, '$1<span style="color: white">$2</span>$3');
console.log('result1:', result1);

let regex2 = /(?<=<a [^>]*>)(.*?)(?=<\/a>)/gi;
let result2 = input.replace(regex2, '<span style="color: white">$1</span>');
console.log('result2:', result2);
```

Output:

```
result1: <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span style="color: white">Twitter/</span></a>
result2: <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span style="color: white">Twitter/</span></a>
```

Explanation of regex1:

- `(<a [^>]*>)` -- capture group 1: anchor tag
- `(.*?)` -- capture group 2: non-greedy scan
- `(<\/a>)` -- capture group 3: anchor end tag
- in replacement part use captured groups `$1`, `$2`, `$3`

Explanation of regex2:

- similar to regex1, but using a positive lookbehind instead of capture group 1, and a positive lookahead instead of capture group 2 (this is not supported by all JavaScript engines)

Answer (score 0):

Using [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector("a");
var anchorText = anchor.textContent;

anchor.innerText = "";
var span = document.createElement("span");
var spanText = document.createTextNode(anchorText);
span.appendChild(spanText)
anchor.appendChild(span);

console.log(anchor.innerHTML);
```

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Twitter/</a>
```

Comment: The OP states node.js, not browser environment

Answer (score 0):

We can also achieve this requirement by simply using [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector("a");
var anchorText = anchor.textContent;

anchor.innerHTML = anchorText.replace(anchorText, `<span style="color: red">${anchorText}</span>`)
```

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Twitter/</a>
```