# Inserting HTML/SVG attribute on a string with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have hundreds of strings, in which I conditionally need to add or remove something. To add a bit more context, this is in fact stringified SVGs, where I want to add/remove attributes to certain nodes. Since I don't have the luxury of a DOM at any stage of this process, and both the input and desired output is a string, I want to do this with a string replacement using RegEx.

The logic is: any substring which looks like an SVG element (`path`, `circle` etc.). which **doesn't** have a `stroke` attribute needs to have it added with a value of `none`.

**Example input:**

```html
<svg>
  <path d="..." fill="black" />
  <path d="..." stroke="black" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

**Desired output:**

```html
<svg>
  <path d="..." fill="red" stroke="none" />
  <path d="..." stroke="black" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="black" stroke="none" />
</svg>
```

Note that the first `<path>` and the `<circle>` has a `stroke="none"` added, while the other `path` remains unchanged.

**What I've tried so far:**

```js
const matcher = /(?<=path)((?!stroke=).)*(?=\/>)/g
const newSvg = oldSvg.replace(matcher, ' $1 stroke=\"none\" ')
```

**Problems**

- I think this is really close , but the output is wrong: `<path " stroke="none" />` (all attributes removed and a `"` character is added).
- This only matches `path` elements. I tried something like `(?<=(path|circle))`, but it seems not to be valid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why does this need to be done with regex? You are using JS already, it seems it would be much easier to examine the content as a document programmatically.

Comment: While it is JavaScript, there is no DOM. It's a Node script which reads the file content (as string) and feeds it inte SVGR (as a string). SVGR then outputs a React component, and I bundle that as a package. The alteration needs to happen before it is fed into SVGR, and at that point it is a string.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags and then decide what you're going to use instead of regex

Comment: You could also try a [nodeJS DOM parser: "How do I parse a HTML page with Node.js"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372972/how-do-i-parse-a-html-page-with-node-js) Other options described [here: "Trying to use the DOMParser with node js"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safer to use a DOM parser in Node.js, see [How do I parse a HTML page with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372972/how-do-i-parse-a-html-page-with-node-js)

You can however use nested regex replaces. Here is a solution to your question that supports the shortened tag format `<tag attrs />`, as well as the close tag format `<tag attrs></tag>`. Tweak `regex2` to support additional tags.

```js
const input = `<svg>
  <path d="..." fill="black" />
  <path d="..." stroke="black" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="black" />
</svg>
<div>Other stuff</div>
<svg>
  <path d="..." fill="black" stroke="green"></path>
  <path d="..."></path>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="black"></circle>
</svg>`;

const regex1 = /(<svg>)(.*?)(<\/svg>)/gis;
const regex2 = /<(path|circle)( .*?)( *\/>|> *<\/\1>)/gis;
const regex3 = /\bstroke=["']/i;
let result = input.replace(regex1, (svg, g1, g2, g3) => {
  return g1 + g2.replace(regex2, (tag, g1, g2, g3) => {
    if(!g2.match(regex3)) {
      return '<' + g1 + g2 + ' stroke="none"' + g3;
    } else {
      return tag;
    }
  }) + g3;
});
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
<svg>
  <path d="..." fill="black" stroke="none" />
  <path d="..." stroke="black" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="black" stroke="none" />
</svg>
<div>Other stuff</div>
<svg>
  <path d="..." fill="black" stroke="green"></path>
  <path d="..." stroke="none"></path>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="black" stroke="none"></circle>
</svg>
```

Explanation of `regex1`:

- `(<svg>)` -- capture group 1 with opening tag
- `(.*?)` -- capture group 2: non-greedy scan until:
- `(<\/svg>)` -- capture group 3 with closing tag

Explanation of `regex2`:

- `<` -- literal `<`
- `(path|circle)` -- capture group 1 with tag name
- `( .*?)` -- capture group 2: tag attributes, e.g. non-greedy scan until:
- `( *\/>|> *<\/\1>)` -- capture group 3: either self closing tag `/>` or `>` and closing tag `</tag>`

Explanation of `regex3` test:

- `\b` -- word boundary
- `stroke=` -- literal text
- `["']` -- quote or single quote char