# how to access xml entries of type <Item> in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

as shown in the below posted code, i am processing a tiff file. the `img` object in the inner-most promise contains some data in a form of key-value.
the object `img.fileDirectory.GDAL_METADATA` contains the data posted below.

now my question is, as i would like to have access to `STATISTICS_MAXIMUM`,`STATISTICS_MEAN`,...etc. how can i have access to contents shown in `GDALMetadata`

**GDALMetadata**

```
<GDALMetadata>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM" sample="0">21.122838228436</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MEAN" sample="0">1.2389914218174</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MINIMUM" sample="0">-4.6630500033646</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_STDDEV" sample="0">2.0382729681586</Item>
</GDALMetadata>
```

**code**:

```
response.on('close', async()=>{
    console.log('Retrieved all data');
    readFile("./test-1.tiff")
    .then((data)=>{
        dataAsArrayBuffer = data.buffer
        fromArrayBuffer(dataAsArrayBuffer)
        .then((geoTIFF)=>{
            geoTIFF.getImage()
            .then((img)=> {
                console.log(img.fileDirectory.GDAL_METADATA);//<==============
                console.log(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getSamplesPerPixel());
            })
            .catch((e)=>console.log("img.errorMessage:",e))
        })
        .catch((e)=> console.log("geoTIFF.errorMessage:",e))
    })
    .catch((e)=> console.log("data.errorMessage:",e))
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NodeJS domparsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js)

For example [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const meta = `<GDALMetadata>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM" sample="0">21.122838228436</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MEAN" sample="0">1.2389914218174</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MINIMUM" sample="0">-4.6630500033646</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_STDDEV" sample="0">2.0382729681586</Item>
</GDALMetadata>`;

const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(meta);
const stats = [...dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("Item")]
 .map(item => ({[item.getAttribute('name')]:+item.textContent})); // convert the string to number using unary plus
console.log(stats);
```

Built-in Browser [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)

```js
const meta = `<GDALMetadata>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM" sample="0">21.122838228436</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MEAN" sample="0">1.2389914218174</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MINIMUM" sample="0">-4.6630500033646</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_STDDEV" sample="0">2.0382729681586</Item>
</GDALMetadata>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc1 = parser.parseFromString(meta, "application/xml");
const stats = [...doc1.querySelectorAll("Item")]
 .map(item => ({[item.getAttribute('name')]:+item.textContent})); // convert the string to number using unary plus
console.log(stats)
```

Comment: should i import the Domparser class?because i receive an error fo "domparser is not defined"

Comment: [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js)

Comment: is it import DOMParser from 'DOMParser'

Comment: No. Please see my update

Comment: can you please tell me what is the three dots in the line of const stats = for?

Comment: [... spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) because querySelectorAll does not implement Array map

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML/XML on server side with Node.js. can be done with parsers such as [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

Try this, it loads your string, finds all `Item` elements, loops them and gets text value. You can then construct results object according to your needs:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const inputData = `<GDALMetadata>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM" sample="0">21.122838228436</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MEAN" sample="0">1.2389914218174</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_MINIMUM" sample="0">-4.6630500033646</Item>
  <Item name="STATISTICS_STDDEV" sample="0">2.0382729681586</Item>
</GDALMetadata>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(inputData, {
      xmlMode: true
    });

const result = {};

// select all Item elements, get text value for each
$('Item').each(function(i, elm) {
    console.log($(this).text());
// construct object attributeName:value
    result[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).text();    
});

console.log(result);
```