# Inside a web worker, how to find html attribute from string?

Tags: javascript, dom, web-worker

Inside a web worker, I have an html string like:

```
"<div id='foo'>  <img src='bar'></img>  <ul id='baz'></ul>  </div>"
```

Is there any library I can import to easily access id and src attributes of the different tags ? Is regex the only way inside a worker ?

Comment: Some XML parsers might help here if you have XHTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540218/a-javascript-parser-for-dom

Comment: @pd40 Inside Web Workers, the DOM API is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solve this problem efficiently:

### Regex

With the risk of getting false positives, you can use something like:

```
var pattern = /<img [^>]*?src=(["'])((?:[^"']+|(?!\1)["'])*)(\1)/i;
var match = string.match(pattern);
var src = match ? match[2] : '';
```

### Built-in parser & messaging

If getting the HTML right is a critical requirement, just let the browser parse the HTML, by passing the string to the caller. Here's a full example:

Caller:

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    if (!e.data) return;
    if (e.data.method === 'getsrc') {
        // Unlike document.createElement, etc, the following method does not 
        //  load the image when the HTML is parsed
        var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
        doc.body.innerHTML = e.data.data;
        var images = doc.getElementsByTagName('img');
        var result = [];
        for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
            result.push(images[i].getAttribute('src'));
        }
        worker.postMessage({
            messageID: e.data.messageID,
            result: result
        });
    } else if (e.data.method === 'debug') {
        console.log(e.data.data);
    }
});
```

worker.js

```
// A simple generic messaging API
var callbacks = {};
var lastMessageID = 0;
addEventListener('message', function(e) {
   if (callbacks[e.data.messageID]) {
       callbacks[e.data.messageID](e.data.result);
   }
});
function sendRequest(method, data, callback) {
    var messageID = ++lastMessageID;
    if (callback) callbacks[messageID] = callback;
    postMessage({
        method: method,
        data: data,
        messageID: messageID
    });
}

// Example:
sendRequest('getsrc',
    '<img src="foo.png">' + 
    "<img src='bar.png'>" + 
    '<textarea><img src="should.not.be.visible"></textarea>',
    function(result) {
        sendRequest('debug', 'Received: ' + result.join(', '));
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, almost 11 years later, there are some more options.

For the purpose of just scanning through the elements in an HTML string [`htmlparse2`](https://feedic.com/htmlparser2/) is often more than enough:

```
// Demo using htmlparser2 in a web worker
// `onopentag` version

const WORKER_URL = URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob(
    [
      `
import { Parser } from 'https://esm.sh/htmlparser2@9.0.0';

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  const ids = [];
  const srcs = [];
      
  const parser = new Parser({
    onopentag(name, attributes) {
      if ('id' in attributes) {
        ids.push({ value: attributes.id, tag: name });
      }
      if ('src' in attributes) {
        srcs.push({ value: attributes.src, tag: name });
      }
    },
  });
  parser.write(event.data);
  parser.end();
      
  self.postMessage({ ids, srcs });
});
`,
    ],
    { type: 'text/javascript' }
  )
);

type AttributeMatch = {
  value: string;
  tag: string;
};

type FromWorker = {
  ids: AttributeMatch[];
  srcs: AttributeMatch[];
};

const worker = new Worker(WORKER_URL, { type: 'module' });

worker.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  const { ids, srcs } = e.data as FromWorker;
  for (const id of ids) {
    console.log(`id="${id.value}" on <${id.tag}>`);
  }

  for (const src of srcs) {
    console.log(`src="${src.value}" on <${src.tag}>`);
  }
});

const input =
  '<div id="foo">  <img src="bar"></img>  <ul id="baz"></ul>  </div>';

worker.postMessage(input);

/*  console output:
    id="foo" on <DIV>
    id="baz" on <UL>
    src="bar" on <IMG>
 */
```

`htmlparser2` is an event-based parser and implementing the [`onopentag` event handler](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2/wiki/Parser-options#user-content-events) is sufficient for the original use case.

Alternately `onopentagname` and `onattribute` could be used:

```
// Demo using htmlparser2 in a web worker
// `onopentagname` and `onattribute` version

import { Parser } from 'https://esm.sh/htmlparser2@9.0.0';

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  const ids = [];
  const srcs = [];
  let tag = '';
  const parser = new Parser({
    onopentagname(name) {
      tag = name;
    },
    onattribute(name, value) {
      switch (name) {
        case 'id': {
          ids.push({ value, tag });
          return;
        }
        case 'src': {
          srcs.push({ value, tag });
          return;
        }
      }
    },
  });
  parser.write(event.data);
  parser.end();

  self.postMessage({ ids, srcs });
});
```

[LinkeDOM](https://webreflection.medium.com/linkedom-a-jsdom-alternative-53dd8f699311) ([GitHub](https://github.com/WebReflection/linkedom)) is a more enriched alternative that can be extremely useful as it provides a [lot of the familiar DOM](https://github.com/WebReflection/linkedom#faq) API functions, including [`document.createNodeIterator()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator) and [`document.createTreeWalker()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker):

```
// Demo using linkedom/worker in a web worker
import { parseHTML, NodeFilter } from 'https://esm.sh/linkedom@0.15.3/worker';

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  const ids = [];
  const srcs = [];

  const { document } = parseHTML(event.data);
  const i = document.createNodeIterator(document, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);

  for (let element = i.nextNode(); element !== null; element = i.nextNode()) {
    const id = element.getAttribute('id');
    if (id) ids.push({ value: id, tag: element.tagName });

    const src = element.getAttribute('src');
    if (src) srcs.push({ value: src, tag: element.tagName });
  }

  self.postMessage({ ids, srcs });
});
```

Note that in `linkedom/worker` the [`HTMLCanvasElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) is essentially a stub.