# Replace all <a> tags in HTML string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Let's suppose that I have an HTML string containing some `<a href="..">` tags. How can I replace all of them to translate this:

```
<a href="http://www.mylink.com">whatever</a>
```

into this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openLink('http://www.mylink.com')">whatever</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use a regex for this?

Comment: [Obligatory link.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2846923)

Comment: Ok, i don't need to use a regex, just a way to replace the links in that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex on your string:

```
var re = new RegExp("<a href=\"([^\"]+)\"", "g");
  result = 
    string.replace(re, 
      "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"openLink('$1')\"");
```

http://regex101.com/r/wN0aB2

---

**Update**
To account for attributes before the `href`, you could use:

```
var re = new RegExp("<a([^>]* )href=\"([^\"]+)\"", "g");
  result = 
    string.replace(re, 
      "<a$1href=\"#\" onclick=\"openLink('$2')\"");
```

http://regex101.com/r/bZ0nO4

Comment: this one works fine globally for all links! thanks! :)

Comment: @FidoBoy using regexp is very bad idea! http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2846923

Comment: @d_inevitable truth be told - that link has been over-used in SO for a very long time - and although it is very amusing, for specific tasks where the input is predictable, and the objective is specific, using regexp _may_ be the most elegant, succinct and performant.

Comment: @UriAgassi maybe. But in this very case it is very wrong to use regexp.

Comment: Ok, but if i don't use regex, how can i replace links then?

Comment: I'm using this inside an AngularJS filter, i just need to avoid default behavior on all <a> tags

Comment: Can't use DOM like in your example cause AngularJS doesn't work that way (can't change DOM directly bypassing AngularJS framework). Also, i can't use jQuery cause i don't have that library loaded.

Comment: @FidoBoy I am not familiar with AngularJS, but don't they have a way of attaching event listeners? You can always attach it to document, and let it bubble up, check if event.target is a anchor and then prevent the default.

Comment: @FidoBoy if that doesn't help you should ask a AngularJS question. You really should not search html tags with RegExp on the browser! I can pretty much guarantee that there is a better and easier solution.

Comment: the only limitation that i see in this answer is that this: <a rel="text" href="http://www.server.com"> doesn't work. Other than this, i'm not using this against DOM, but against a simple HTML string that i get from a REST service.

Comment: @FidoBoy you can still use the DOM parser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9540602/1238764

Comment: so, this answer could be enhanced using this: /<a(.*)href="([^"]+)"/g isn't it @Uri Agassi?

Comment: @UriAgassi your update will not work with `<a id=">myid" href="http://example.com">example</a>` - or an html comment there.

Comment: @d_inevitable - you are right, it won't. It would work for 99.999% of normal HTML fragments. If the OP does not expect freak attributes, I think this would suffice.

Comment: @UriAgassi correct, but again you are in browser. you have an excellent DOM parser, so why use regexp for html parsing, if you can have something that is both faster and more reliable?

Comment: @d_inevitable - a DOM parser will _not_ be faster than a straight forward regular expression. You don't _always_ need a sledge hammer to break eggs.

Comment: @UriAgassi how will it not be faster? Remember we are on the client here. So the dom will be parsed anyway at some point. Otherwise I would advise doing this server side.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use RegExp, because it is very hard, if not impossible, to safely restrict the matches to just the anchor links that you are targeting. Instead you should use the very DOM parser that naturally every browser has built in.

And don't use `onclick` html attributes, because there is no need to tweak html in javascript to add javascript event handlers and it prevents users from using things like right click -> 'open in new tab', or 'copy link address'.

Use this:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0 ; i != anchors.length ; i++) {
  anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {

     var href = this.getAttribute("href");

     if (href) {
       event.preventDefault();
       openLink(href);
     }
  });
}
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jASAj/1)

Or you can use a delegated event handler:

```
function openLink(href) {
 alert("openLink " + href);   
}

document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === "A" && event.target.href) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        openLink(event.target.href);
    }
});
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jASAj/3/)

Or you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$("a[href]").click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   openLink($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jASAj/2/)

Comment: Why do you advise against using onclick html attributes?

Comment: @stackErr because it involves tweaking html code at runtime, while it can be done purely in javascript.

Comment: @FidoBoy perhaps the delegated event handler will help?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using JS.

Find all anchor elements in DOM and setAttributes:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i =0; i < anchors.length; i++)
{       var myLink = anchors[i].getAttribute("href");
        anchors[i].setAttribute("href","#");
        anchors[i].setAttribute("onclick", "openLink('"+ myLink +"');");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = subject.replace(/<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*)<\/a>/img, "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"openLink('$1')\">$2</a>");
```

http://regex101.com/r/dK2oU5

Comment: I like the `img` flags. Makes it look like it has something to do with images :P

Comment: only works with first link… not with all links in the html string

Comment: I would advise against this...what if tomorrow you need to add/remove another attribute? Are you going to post another SO question and get someone else to post another Regex solution?