# regex to remove script tag allowing certain type in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex of the like of

```
/<script[^>]*>([\\S\\s]*?)<\/script>/img
```

That I will use to replace script tag unless it match a certain type of script, we have color schemes in my app and that must go through, but injecting anything else must be removed.

This is allowed

```
<script type="colorScheme">..</script>
```

anything else must be removed, but I can't get quite to right regex, I cannot also transform this in dom nodes.

A document fragment does not keep head and tags contained in the head. You guys in the comment please see [Can I load an entire HTML document into a document fragment in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474710/can-i-load-an-entire-html-document-into-a-document-fragment-in-internet-explorer)

Thanks a ton!!

Comment: This should be done with a parser, not a regex.

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, what you need is a regexp that matches  where XXX can be a set of valid values.

If that's the case, you need a regexp like this:

```
/<script type="(value1|value2|value3)">(.*?)<\/script>/img
```

In Javascript:

```
var regexp = /<script type="(value1|value2|value3)">(.*?)<\/script>/img;
var match = regex.exec(regexp);
console.log('type: ' + match[1]);
console.log('body: ' + match[2]);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Well im looking to do the inverse IO want to do a replace on script tag for an empty string unless it match the colorScheme type. After that I inject this code in an empty iframe

Comment: Can you edit your response? code does not show trough in comments

Comment: OK, so in case it doesn't match do the following: s/<script type="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/script>/<script type="">\2<\/script>/img; I tried this in Perl, \2 means the second matched expression. I don't recall how to do that in Javascript.

Comment: It seems Javascript uses the same syntax for backreferences http://evolt.org/node/36435 How is it? Does it do the job?