# Append stuff the right way

Tags: javascript, append

I'm building myself a little js library and I've come across a problem with the `append` and `prepend` methods. This is my current setup

```
prepend: function(str) {
    this.node.innerHTML = str + this.node.innerHTML;
},
append: function(str) {
    this.node.innerHTML += str;
}
```

They both do work as expected, content is being added, but unfortunately all event listeners of elements that are inside the tag I'm modifying are being lost. It's funny how I didn't figure that may cause an issue. Anyway I tried looking at jQuery to see how they're doing it but their code is apparently not meant to be understood by me. I tried looking up other questions but didn't really find a solution for this.

How can I achieve this without losing my listeners?

Comment: jQuery builds actual DOM nodes with the internal DOMManip function, that way all elements are appended with the native appendChild, prepended with insertBefore etc. and innerHTML is never used.

Comment: @adeneo so it turns out to be a harsh job I guess, but how would I split an html string into nodes :/

Comment: You wouldn't, you would parse the string with the browsers parser, for instance by setting the string as the content of a documentFragment, then extract the nodes and insert them into the actual DOM.

Comment: see the accepted ans of my Q http://stackoverflow.com/q/11515383/908879

Comment: @adeneo I'm sorry could you elaborate, set the string as the content of a documentFragment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474710/can-i-load-an-entire-html-document-into-a-document-fragment-in-internet-explorer/7539198#7539198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use insertAdjacentHTML:

```
prepend: function(str) {
    this.node.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", str);
},
append: function(str) {
    this.node.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", str);
}
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I'm looking for, I can't believe firefox doesn't support it `:<`

Comment: According to MDN Firefox version 8.0 and above supports `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Comment: Actually I was looking at old information, MDN states that all major browsers currently support this, even though it is not in the ECMA. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you move the elements around the DOM as objects rather than a primitive string representation, their attached events and other meta will be maintained.

You'll need to utilize the DOM's `appendChild` and `insertBefore` methods. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QMLpL/2/

Here is your updated snippet:

```
prepend: function(newNode) {
    this.node.insertBefore(newNode,this.node.firstChild);
},
append: function(newNode) {
    this.node.appendChild(newNode);
}
```

The updated snippet expects a DOM node rather than a string.

---

If you are expecting a string, consider utilizing the string as a CDATA node:

```
node = document.createTextNode(str);
```

Enhanced fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QMLpL/3/

Usage:

```
prepend: function(str) {
    newNode = document.createTextNode(str);
    this.node.insertBefore(newNode,this.node.firstChild);
},
append: function(str) {
    newNode = document.createTextNode(str);
    this.node.appendChild(newNode);
}
```

---

The contents of the linked fiddle are as follows.

HTML:

```
<div id="one">
    <p><a id="clicky" href="#">Hello World</a></p>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var clicky = document.getElementById('clicky');
clicky.onclick = function() {
    console.log('clicked!');
    return false;
};

function append(target,node) {
    if ( typeof node === 'string' ) {
        node = document.createTextNode(node); // cast string as CDATA
    }
    target.appendChild(node);
}

function prepend(target,node) {
    if ( typeof node === 'string' ) {
        node = document.createTextNode(node);
    }
    target.insertBefore(node,target.firstChild);
}

var twoDiv = document.getElementById('two');
append(twoDiv,clicky);

var newElement = document.createElement('p');
newElement.onclick = function() {
    console.log('clicked the p');
    return false;
};
newElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Dolor sit amet.')); // add a CDATA node to the new P element
prepend(twoDiv,newElement);

append(twoDiv,'Waddup?');
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to append html strings, but this would be my alternative. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: @php_nub_qq I'm a bit confused, if you have a string representation of HTML why would you be interested in maintaining the events of the children? If the children have events, that would mean you have the parent-most node object in your repertoire. Dealing with the raw DOM node would be faster than serializing it as a string, then having the DOM re-parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's what might work,
I'm not sure. How about making
a deep clone of the object in question.
And then parsing the new html you want to
to add in another variable. Next looping
recursivly over these 2 objects and adding all
their children to a new one. Finally replacing
the object in question with your new object. This
way the listeners are preserved I think. It won't be
easy to write but it might give you an idea.
Cheers.

Comment: Why parse it yourself when you have an entire DOM engine at your disposal?

Comment: insertAdjacentHTML IS NOT SUPPORTED BY FIREFOX. Keep this in mind. I ment to use the appendChild for the recursive looping. And the innerHTML to create your new merging obj.

Comment: It appears that `insertAdjacentHTML` is supported by all major browsers. See MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.insertAdjacentHTML?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: Well it is now version 24, I believe anyone who hasn't updated since 2012 brought this on their own `:D`

Answer (score 0):

Please user insertBefore() JS HTML DOM METHOD for add string before your element content

[Check MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)

OR user appendChild() JS HTML DOM METHOD for add string after your element content

[Check MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)